# Convert and resize image to png using gm

Tags: node.js, image-processing, graphicsmagick

I want to switch from Image Magick to [Graphics Magick](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm). The following code converts an image to PNG:

```
var ImageMagick = require("imagemagick");

// convert the image
ImageMagick.convert([
    "input.jpg"
  , '-resize'
  , "200x100"
  , "output.png"
], function(err, stdout){
    if (err) { throw err; }
    console.log(">> Done");
});
```

How can I do the same but using Graphics Magick?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `resize` and `write` methods:

```
var Gm = require("gm");

Gm("input.jpg").resize(200, 100, "!").write("output.png", function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('image converted.');
});
```

Note you have to install Graphics Magick binaries:

```
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick
brew install graphicsmagick
```