# Convert image of any format in node.js to 1d array of width * height * 4

Tags: javascript, node.js, qr-code

User uploads an image on facebook which generates a URL similar to 'https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t35.0-12/15491651_1204697686283902_928442274_o.jpg?_nc_ad=z-m&oh=6ac7e5b1672bb01edd785ba074a35882&oe=58521D03' I want to read this image from the URL and convert it to a form suitable for [JSQR library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsqr) which accepts a flat 1d array of RGBA values. How do I do this for any image format

**What have I tried so far?**

I tried the [PNGJS library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pngjs) but it only works on PNG images, how can I do this for any image format? Thanks for your suggestions in advance.

Comment: could you convert the jpg to png then use the library you listed? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27340632/convert-and-resize-image-to-png-using-gm

Comment: if it was that simple, i would have done it, i am not able to find anything that takes a url and gives you a desired image rgba data from any format, been at npmjs for a whole day now

Comment: i feel your frustration, sometimes the most obvious solutions are the ones overlooked though, so figured it was worth a mention. Could you supply the code you have working when the supplied image is a png please

Comment: How about using the `canvas` npm package? Seems to be equivalent to the client side canvas which is able to agnostically convert different types of image files to image-data.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/canvas

Comment: Another solution (although a little cumbersome) could be to run a headless chrome or chromium (or could be a real one with gui), access your internally set up web server, and send the jpg file there to be processed to an array format.